# difference between two dates in sql wih year and month format

Tags: sql

i have two date like this 
-4 year and 6 month
-2 year and 3 month
i want to calculate difference between this two date ?

Comment: (1) Those are not "dates".  So, what are they?  Strings?  Sample data as a *table* would help.  (2) What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a datetime value then you can use Datediff function to calculate the difference between two datetime values in SQL Server.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2004-06-01', '2008-06-01') AS "Number of Days";
```